Execution default-descriptor of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-plugin-plugin:3.7.1:descriptor failed: Unsupported class file major version 66
enter image description here
i have added this in my pom.xml to build the custom maven plugin ,The error "Unsupported class file major version 66" indicates that you are trying to compile or execute code that was compiled with a Java version higher than the one currently configured in your environment.major version 66 corresponds to Java 16 bytecode, which is not compatible with your current Java 17 setup.
Execution default-descriptor of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-plugin-plugin:3.7.1:descriptor failed: Unsupported class file major version 66.

Please include code, not images of code: see Why not upload images of code errors when asking a question. Edit the question and include code fragments.

How does it behave with 3.13.1 of the plugin-plugin?

there is no code for tis only we have to add plugin
